# AngularJS Step wizard, disable progress based on values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui.router to create my views and I have set up this set of states:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    // Set up our state(s)
    $stateProvider.state('designer', {
        url: '/:sport/designer',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/index.tpl.html',
        controller: 'DesignerController',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).state('designer.team', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/team.tpl.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Create your team'
        }
    }).state('designer.kit', {
        url: '/kit',
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/kit.tpl.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Choose your garments'
        }
    }).state('designer.design', {
        url: '/design',
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/design.tpl.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Choose your design'
        }
    }).state('designer.refine', {
        url: '/refine',
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/refine.tpl.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Refine your design'
        }
    }).state('designer.order', {
        url: '/order',
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/order.tpl.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Order your kit'
        }
    }).state('designer.save', {
        url: '/save',
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/save.tpl.html',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Save your kit',
            requireLogin: true
        }
    });
}])
```

The index template looks like this:

```
<div class="container designer">
    <div class="row designer-header">
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-include="'/app/designer/tpls/header.tpl.html'">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" ng-include="'/app/designer/tpls/navigation.tpl.html'">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-include="'/app/designer/tpls/total.tpl.html'" ng-hide="controller.garments.loading">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row designer-body">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

The **navigation** include looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-designer">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="designer-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".team">Your team</a></li>
            <li><a>|</a></li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".kit">Kit</a></li>
            <li><a>|</a></li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".design">Design</a></li>
            <li><a>|</a></li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".refine">Refine</a></li>
            <li><a>|</a></li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".order">Order</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

So, the idea is that I want to build this in steps; i.e. When the page is first loaded I would like the user to only be able to advance to the next step (.kit) when they have filled in the first page, which looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" ng-show="controller.colours.data && controller.colours.data.length === 0">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        You must have at least one colour in the database before you can create a team / kit.
    </div>

    <alert-error error="controller.colours.error"></alert-error>

    <form name="teamForm" novalidate ng-show="!controller.colours.loading && !controller.colours.error">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="teamName">Team name</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">1</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teamName" placeholder="Enter your team name" ng-model="controller.model.team.data.name" ng-change="controller.saveSession()" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="colours">Colours</label>
            <div class="picker colour-picker">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">2</div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colours" placeholder="Choose your colours" disabled>
                </div>

                <ul class="picker-dropdown list-inline form-control">
                    <li ng-repeat="colour in controller.colours.data" ng-class="{ 'active': controller.matchColour(colour) }">
                        <a href style="background-color: #{{ colour.hex }};" ng-click="controller.setColour(colour)"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <p><a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ui-sref="designer.kit">Choose teamwear</a></p>
</div>
```

All the other "tabs" should be disabled. And then similarly, when I advance to the **kit** view I would like the user only to be able to advance when they have made a selection, this is the kit page:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" ng-show="controller.garments.data && controller.garments.data.length === 0">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        It appears that your sport does not have any garments associated with it.
    </div>

    <alert-error error="controller.garments.error"></alert-error>

    <form ng-show="!controller.garments.loading && !controller.garments.error">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="clubName">Club name</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">1</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clubName" placeholder="Choose your teamwear">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="picker garment-picker">
            <ul class="picker-dropdown list-inline">
                <li ng-repeat="garment in controller.garments.data" ng-class="{ 'active': controller.matchGarment(garment) }"><a href ng-click="controller.setGarment(garment)">{{ garment.title }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>

    <p><a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ui-sref="designer.design">Design teamwear</a></p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?
I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: store the progress in a service and enable/disable the tabs based on the values you retrieve from the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this myself with the aid of **resolve**.
Here are my **states** now:

```
// Set up our state(s)
$stateProvider.state('designer', {
    url: '/:sport/designer',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/index.tpl.html',
    controller: 'DesignerController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    resolve: {
        model: ['DesignerService', function (service) {

            console.log('hi');

            // return our model
            return service.get();
        }]
    }
}).state('designer.team', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/team.tpl.html',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Create your team'
    }
}).state('designer.kit', {
    url: '/kit',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/kit.tpl.html',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Choose your garments'
    },
    resolve: {
        model: ['$q', 'DesignerService', function ($q, service) {

            // Defer our promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Get our model
            var model = service.get();

            // If we have selected our colours and our team name
            if (model.team.data.colours.length > 0 && model.team.data.name) {

                // resolve our promise
                deferred.resolve(model);
            } else {

                // Otherwise reject our promise
                deferred.reject();
            }

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
    }
}).state('designer.design', {
    url: '/design',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/design.tpl.html',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Choose your design'
    },
    resolve: {
        model: ['$q', 'DesignerService', function ($q, service) {

            // Defer our promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Get our model
            var model = service.get();

            // If we have selected any garments
            if (model.kit.data.garments.length > 0) {

                // resolve our promise
                deferred.resolve(model);
            } else {

                // Otherwise reject our promise
                deferred.reject();
            }

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
    }
}).state('designer.refine', {
    url: '/refine',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/refine.tpl.html',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Refine your design'
    },
    resolve: {
        model: ['$q', 'DesignerService', function ($q, service) {

            // Defer our promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Get our model
            var model = service.get();

            // If we have selected our design
            if (model.kit.data.design) {

                // resolve our promise
                deferred.resolve(model);
            } else {

                // Otherwise reject our promise
                deferred.reject();
            }

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
    }
}).state('designer.order', {
    url: '/order',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/order.tpl.html',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Order your kit'
    },
    resolve: {
        model: ['$q', 'DesignerService', function ($q, service) {

            // Defer our promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Get our model
            var model = service.get();

            // TODO: check for the applied colours
            if (model.kit.data.templates.length > 50) {

                // resolve our promise
                deferred.resolve(model);
            } else {

                // Otherwise reject our promise
                deferred.reject();
            }

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
    }
}).state('designer.save', {
    url: '/save',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/save.tpl.html',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Save your kit',
        requireLogin: true
    }
});
```

I admit the resolves are rather large, but I will find a way to make them smaller.
On a side note, because I am using resolve I can inject it into my controller without having to call the service again, i.e.:

```
.controller('DesignerController', ['$stateParams', 'model', function ($stateParams, model) {
    var self = this,
        slug = $stateParams.sport;

    // Kit model
    self.model = model;
}])
```

**note:** that the **model** is inject after all other dependencies. That makes a difference.